# Google analytics trace user behaviour

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm new in GA, but I understand that there are some metrics at a user level. Is there a way to trace a user, so we can understand his history in the site?

Questions like: how many users did more than 10 visits in the last month?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at custom segments. You can easily create a custom segment to look specifically at users who had 10 or more sessions, and then just look at your time range.

Here is what your segment would look like:

[image]